# Display a row with total amount of shift wise

Tags: php, codeigniter

I provide staff members to a site. They work shit wise Day and Night.
To make monthly Invoice I display the staff according to Shift wise.
Like

```
 Day Shift
 Emp Name      Days     Amount
   A            30       1200
   B            25       1000
 Night Shift
   C            27       1100
   D            26       1050
```

I want to display a row with total Amount Shift Wise
I have this code

```
 <?php 
 $temp='';
 foreach ( $rows as $row) 

{
```

///To Display Shift Row///////

```
    if($temp!=$row->shift_type) 
    {
     ?>
   <tr><td style="font-weight:bold"><?php echo $row->shift_type;?> Shift</td></tr>  
   <tr style=" border-top:3px solid #CCC">

   <th style="text-align:center">Staff Name</th>

   <th style="text-align:center"> Days</th>
   <th style="text-align:center"> Amount</th>
   </tr>
   <?php $temp = $row->shift_type;
    }
?>
```

////To Display Staff Members with Salry////
     
       first_name.$row->last_name; ?>

```
   <td align="center"><?php  echo $row->week_days; ?></td>
   <td align="center">$<?php echo $weekdaysamount= $row->week_days*$row->week_day_rate; 
   $totalweekdaysamount+=$weekdaysamount;?>
  </td>

  </tr>
  <?php  }   ?>
```

This make the total of all rows . I want a row with total of Shift wise.
Should be like this

```
 Day Shift
    Emp Name      Days     Amount
     A            30       1200
     B            25       1000
    Total                  2200   
 Night Shift
     C            27       1100
     D            26       1050
    Total                  2150
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? A new row with all `Days` OR `Amount`?

Comment: Do you want total number of employees worked for specific shit...?

what u want exactly. **please provide expected answer**.

Comment: I want to display a row with total amount of Shift Wise
like 
Day
A
B
Total  2200
Night
C
D
Total 2150

Comment: so, there will be a unique column in database that will distinguish `Day shift` with `Night shift`, what is the name and value in that column?

Comment: There is a field already and displaying data according to this exactly. but I want to make total amount in loop shift wise

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<table style="width:100%">
<?php 
require("stackoverflow_connect.php");
$extract=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE shift_type='Day'");
  echo 'Day Shift';
      echo '
      <tr>
      <td>Emp Name</td>
      <td>Days</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
      </tr>
      ';
$total=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($extract))
{
  $total=$total+($row['week_day_rate']*$row['week_day']);
    echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['week_day'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['week_day_rate']*$row['week_day'].'</td>  
    </tr>';
}
echo '<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Day Total</td>
      <td>'.$total.'</td>
      </tr>';
$extract_n=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE shift_type='Night'");

$total=0;
while($row_n=mysql_fetch_assoc($extract_n))
{
  $total=$total+($row['week_day_rate']*$row['week_day']);
    echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['week_day'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['week_day_rate']*$row['week_day'].'</td>  
    </tr>';
}
echo '<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Night Total</td>
      <td>'.$total.'</td>
      </tr>';
?>
</table>
<html>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you then confirm it. Else tell something missing in it i will correct it out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the total shift wise,first order the result by the shift_type when fetching data.Then while calculating check the shift_type and if it is different from the previous record reset the value to zero.Something like below should work

```
 $previous_shilft='';//Initally outside the foreach


    if($previous_shilft!=$row->shift_type && !empty($previous_shilft)){
echo '<tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td>'.$totalweekdaysamount.'</td>
     </tr>';//Display the row
          }
 if($previous_shilft!=$row->shift_type){
    $totalweekdaysamount=0;
    }
    $totalweekdaysamount+=$weekdaysamount;
    $previous_shilft=$row->shift_type;//For next loop check change the value
```

Comment: how this will display the row with total value.

Comment: Check the answer now.If that helps you.